# Graph like implementation in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures

So I have an object(lets call it the Head) which has a list of objects C(C1,C2,C3,...) , T(T1,T2,...) and M(M1,M2,...) and all of these are interrelated like for e.g.

```
Head -> C1,C2,C3 , T1 , T2 , M1 , M2
T1   -> C1,C2  
T2   -> C2,C3 
M1   -> C1, C2,C3 
M2   -> C1, C2
```

where "->" implies "related to"

```
So Head has 7 successors and 0 predecessors
   T1 has 1 predecessor(Head ) and 2 successors(C1,C2)
   M1 has 1 predecessor(Head ) and 3 successors(C1,C2,C3)
and so on
```

I thought of creating a class with successors and predecessors as its properties but am not sure how to build this graph like structure from the Head object?

Comment: To me, it's still not clear what is your question

Comment: There must be something that could play a role of unique primary key. Create `Dictionary<keyType, NodeType>` and put all nodes there, so when you're creating your graph you can check if node is already part of a it (and simply link to it) or you have to add new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That really depends on what you need to do with the graph. The easiest storage would be a `List<Node>` where each Node object contains links to its predecessors and successors. (And some data of course)

You can do pretty much everything on this list, but an algorithm might have a certain data structure which makes it more efficient/faster. Convert to this as needed. For initialization for example:

```
class Example
{
    public List<Node> InitGraph()
    {
        var nodes = new Dictionary<string, Node>();

        nodes.Add("Head", new Node("Head"));
        nodes.Add("T1", new Node("T1"));
        nodes.Add("T2", new Node("T2"));
        // While that works, a method is nicer:
        nodes.Add("C1");

        // These two lines should really be factored out to a single method call
        nodes["Head"].Successors.Add(nodes["T1"]);
        nodes["T1"].Predecessors.Add(nodes["Head"]);
        nodes["Head"].Successors.Add(nodes["T2"]);
        nodes["T2"].Predecessors.Add(nodes["Head"]);

        // Yes. Much nicer
        nodes.Connect("Head", "C1");
        nodes.Connect("T1", "C1");
        nodes.Connect("T2", "C1");

        var nodelist = new List<Node>(nodes.Values);
        return nodelist;
    }
}
public static class NodeHelper
{        
    public static void Add(this Dictionary<string, Node> dict, string nodename)
    {
        dict.Add(nodename, new Node(nodename));
    }
    public static void Connect(this Dictionary<string, Node> dict, string from, string to)
    {
        dict[ from ].Successors.Add(dict[ to ]);
        dict[ to ].Predecessors.Add(dict[ from ]);
    }
}

public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Coolness { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Predecessors { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Successors { get; set; }
    public Node()
    {
        Coolness = 1;
    }

    public Node(string name) : this()
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

For the actual initialization phase, I'd read it from a file. First all Nodes and then all Edges connecting them. Make some nice Load/Save Methods to make sure it's all consistent.

---

While I have expanded the example (and it compiles) I left testing to the reader. It should give you a good starting point.

Comment: yes that is exactly what i have right now..a List,Node< with links to predecessors and successors . But I am confused as to how I can build this relation like Do i iterate over the head object for all the C objects first and add to the list and then iterate the T/M objects and lookup the related C object ?

Comment: First add all the nodes. Then, for each edge, make the connection. Finally, (optional) check the connection of the graph.

Comment: Your Connect method doesnt use from, to