# Decoupling Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

After looking at major pattern designs, I can't seem to make up my mind around the best to one to decouple classes in a big hierarchy system, specially were it concerns on avoiding injecting a Parent property in EVERY object along the way.

Some of the premises are:

1. A child might me removed from one parent and added to another.
2. Somewhere down the hierarchy, I need to access Parent of type X.
3. As mentioned before, I would like to avoid injecting a Parent (either by property or constructor) to it's children.
4. I have 1..1 and 1...N cardinalities.
5. The hierarchy from root to furthest leaf is quite extent.

If it was a small project, I would be fine with this (pseudo code):

```
public abstract class BaseObject()
{
    public BaseObject Parent { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject() : BaseObject
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public ParentObject[] Parent { get; set; }
}

public class ParentObject() : BaseObject
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public ChildObject[] Parent { get; set; }
}

public class ChildObject() : BaseObject
{
    public int Id { get; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //...navigate through Parent to get RootObject (or any other type in between that I might need)...
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me out to the right direction?

Comment: Have you looked at the `composite pattern`  [composite-design-pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/composite-design-pattern) ?

Comment: One of the definitions of patterns is `A solution to a problem in a context`. What problem are you trying to solve here? And why would there be a `Parent` property in the first place? How big is the big hierarchy and why *not* have a `Parent`? Instead of base classes you can use interfaces and extension methods

Comment: I would consider creating a Dictionary that maintains the relationships, instead of putting the relations in the Child/Parent objects.

Comment: @RyanWilson, I did, as well as Mediator, Visitor, Context, Dependency Injection, etc. Context would be a good solution in concept, because I need to 'store' only a few key types from the object tree/graph, but I don't see how to 'choose' the right context. How ObjectJ, in a hierarchy starting at ObjectA, knows that it belongs to branch ObjectC, without passing it out by parameter.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I'm trying to reach scalability, modularity and testable models, in a complex data structure. The `Parent` property would be necessary to know part of the branch where the leaf is, to be used by the leaf. The branch depth can go easily a couple of dozens. And I don't want the `Parent` because maintenance will be hell! I'm still formatted in the traditional Parent/Child model that I don't see how interfaces would suffice.

Comment: @qaabaam, that looks like the `Context Pattern`, and I was about to say the same I said to @RyanWilson, but I guess I could, when adding `ObjectB` to `ObjectA`, store that relationship, and so forth, so when I get to `ObjectJ` being added to `ObjectI`, I would only need to relate them, an later on search the dictionary, like I would recursively in the `Parent` property. Could that be it?

Comment: @cneves that's a vague description, not an actual problem. That's not what patterns are for. There may be *several* ways to solve the same problem but some of them will be more useful or more *harmful* based on the actual circumstances. If you want to store a hierarchy without modifying your entities, create or use a tree, graph or hierarchical container. There are several libraries in NuGet. BUT the best one will depend on how you want to use it. Some make searching for children faster. Some make searching for subsets faster. There are a *lot* of tree structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these requirements remind me [graph data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)):

- A child might me removed from one parent and added to another.
- Somewhere down the hierarchy, I need to access Parent of type X.
- As mentioned before, I would like to avoid injecting a Parent (either by property or constructor) to it's children.
- I have 1..1 and 1...N cardinalities.
- The hierarchy from root to furthest leaf is quite extent.

The easiest storage would be `List<Node>` [where each node contains links to its predecessors and successors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21685653):

```
class Example
{
    public List<Node> InitGraph()
    {
        var nodes = new Dictionary<string, Node>();

        nodes.Add("Head", new Node("Head"));
        nodes.Add("T1", new Node("T1"));
        nodes.Add("T2", new Node("T2"));
        // While that works, a method is nicer:
        nodes.Add("C1");

        // These two lines should really be factored out to a single method call
        nodes["Head"].Successors.Add(nodes["T1"]);
        nodes["T1"].Predecessors.Add(nodes["Head"]);
        nodes["Head"].Successors.Add(nodes["T2"]);
        nodes["T2"].Predecessors.Add(nodes["Head"]);

        // Yes. Much nicer
        nodes.Connect("Head", "C1");
        nodes.Connect("T1", "C1");
        nodes.Connect("T2", "C1");

        var nodelist = new List<Node>(nodes.Values);
        return nodelist;
    }
}
```

and `NodeHelper` class:

```
public static class NodeHelper
{        
    public static void Add(this Dictionary<string, Node> dict, string nodename)
    {
        dict.Add(nodename, new Node(nodename));
    }
    public static void Connect(this Dictionary<string, Node> dict, string from, string to)
    {
        dict[ from ].Successors.Add(dict[ to ]);
        dict[ to ].Predecessors.Add(dict[ from ]);
    }
}
```

and `Node` class:

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Coolness { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Predecessors { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Successors { get; set; }
    public Node()
    {
        Coolness = 1;
    }

    public Node(string name) : this()
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @StepUp, this seems a good starting point for me. +1 for introducing the Helper. To apply this concept in a real world, I have a few comments though: why identify nodes by `string`? Why not `Node<T>`, and actually have the object stored, maybe with a [WeakReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.weakreference)? Being a disruptive approach, instead of a `InitGraph` example, maybe a `GraphManager` class to provide `Add` and `Remove` functionalities, whenever a new object must be associated?

Comment: @cneves you can upvote or mark my reply as an answer to simplify the future search of other users. It is like saying "thanks" at stackoverflow :). [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/309682)

Comment: @cneves yeah, you can use `Node<T>`. I think, it is a good way to create  `GraphManager`. In my reply, it is just extension methods